# Modify JHipster generate code for login page

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application, jhipster

I generated a project using JHipster And i want to make a few modifications to it. I want the first page to be the login page, a simple one without a header, menu or footer. I saw that in the generated code the components are added from index.

```
<page-ribbon></page-ribbon>
<div ui-view="navbar" ng-cloak></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="well" ui-view="content">
        <!-- Angular views -->
    </div>

    <div class="footer" ng-cloak>
        <p data-translate="footer">This is your footer</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know what is the best way to modify this to show the login page at first is user isn't logged in. If the user is logged in I want to show the home page of the application

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the quickest fix available to solve your problem, is just to open "src/main/webapp/app/home/home.state.js" and add the ROLE_USER authority to data.authorities, like

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
        parent: 'app',
        url: '/',
        data: {
            authorities: ['ROLE_USER']
        },
        views: {
            'content@': {
                templateUrl: 'app/home/home.html',
                controller: 'HomeController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            }
        },
        ...
```

This will automatically route yourself to "accessdenied", but automatically opens the login dialog

a better solution would be to add a login ui to the homeview, if not authenticated, or just to upgrade the login components to a own route.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me in understanding the structure of the project, but my problem persists. I want a login page without the navbar and footer. If I use your method it will show me a modal and I do not want that

Comment: in this case you need to add a new route "login" and force the routing to it, when no user is authenticated. The new route I would use with the login controller, if possible (that means, it works when not a modal), otherwise copy & paste or change that controller for usage on a full page controller. If you stuck I try to put some sample code as answer

Comment: My problem is that i do not know how to show just the login page without navbar and footer because it is included in the index.html, like I said in the post. I don't want to delete that code as it is useful for the rest of the application. Also I have created a new layout and controller and the functionality works now.

Comment: you could either use a component with css, which lies above all that so it is pseudo-invisible (this is hacky), or you maintain $rootScope variables holding a boolean state, whether the user is on login route, or not, and switches the navbar and footer using ng-if. I also would look if it is possible to route your login to the top ui-view, where all other stuff is loaded...

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I solved the problem by using a variable in the rootScope that is set from the auth service. If you think of another way please let me know. Thanks